# Simplest way to create a new object based on the original, but without a few fields

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to create a new object based on the original with all the fields, but without some of them. In my current implementation I enumerate all the fields, and exclude don't needed:

```
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

var keys = _.keys(obj);
_.remove(keys, 'c');

var obj2 = _.pick(obj1, keys);
console.log(obj2); // => { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

But I don't like that, can somebody suggest more easiest way? For example in mongoose, `find` method accepts a string of fields, separated by comma, and to exclude any field, I need to add `minus` symbol only: `name email -password`.

Comment: Can you write a couple of test cases to illustrate input and output? For example: `smartFilter({a: 1, b: 2}, ["a", "-b"]) === {a: 1} // true`, I just don't understand what you're trying to do. Also, what have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I already have a solution, I've added it to my question. But I'm looking for the alternatives: less code with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) it is pretty simple, just use `._omit()`

```
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

var obj2 = _.omit(obj1, ["c"]);
```

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/bpursley/hnh5ecam/

Comment: Thanks it's that what I need

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var obj2 = {},
    forbiddenProperties = ['c', 'd'];

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function (key) {
   if (forbiddenProperties.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
      obj2[key] = obj1[key];
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that does this, and you don't need to rely on underscore.

```
function partialClone(obj, excluded) {
  var clone = {};

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (!excluded.includes(key)) {
      clone[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }

  return clone;
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unscsprt/ozr74tjv/)